# Computing the Mean of Around Values

Tags: probability-or-statistics, around

I understand the computation of the uncertainty of independent Around values to be based on the following first order approximation
$$
    \delta f(x,y)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{$\delta $f}}{\partial x}\text{$\delta $x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\text{$\delta $f}}{\partial y}\text{$\delta $y}\right)^2}.
$$

Thus I compute the uncertainty for the mean of around numbers to be
$$
\delta\text{Mean}\left[\left\{\text{Around}\left[x_1,\text{$\delta $x}_1\right],\text{...}\text{Around}\left[x_{\text{n1}},\text{$\delta $x}_n\right]\right\}\right]=\frac{\sqrt{\text{$\delta $x}_1^2+\text{...}+\text{$\delta $x}_n^2}}{n}
$$

and this seems to work when the uncertainties are different.  For instance Mean[{Around[1,0.5],Around[1,0.25}] = Around[1,0.28]. However, when the uncertainties are equal, Mathematica returns an Around value with uncertainty unchange.  For instance I would expect Mean[{Around[1,0.5],Around[1,0.5}] to return Around[1,0.35] but instead it returns Around[1,0.5]. And if the values are different, I do get the expected result, thus the Mean[{Around[2,0.5],Around[1,0.5]}]=Around[1.5,0.35].

So I'm assuming Mathematica is treating Mean[{Around[1,0.5],Around[1,0.5]}] as two correlated inputs, but why and how would you control this?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me - there is [`AroundReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AroundReplace.html) for the case of correlated quantities, so this should work as it is. My guess is that something inside `Mean` is simplifying the expression for the mean to `(2*Around[1,0.5])/2` before doing any special handling of the `Around` quantities, which is causing the issue. The easiest fix for now is probably to use your own function to compute the mean, e.g. `Total[#]/Length[#] &[{Around[1, 0.5], Around[1, 0.5]}]`

Comment: Please make a report to support@wofram.com

Comment: I agree. There is probably a simplification happening which changes the calculation. I'll submit the note to support@wolfram.com.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: BTW, in more recent releases this issue was resolved.